Error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymodbus.client.sync'
pymodbus is already installed in venv in rasbianOS upon raspberrypi5
$ - pip show pymodbus
Name: pymodbus
Version: 3.6.8
Summary: A fully featured modbus protocol stack in python
Home-page:
Author: Galen Collins, Jan Iversen
Author-email:
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: /home/raspberrypi/OT-Research/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
Any possible solutions ?
